# Push Notifications with RealmDB React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm building a app and i need a way to make a push notification according a date stored in the Database (RealmDB), how can I do this? ? There's a way to do it without make the app run in background and executing querys ? I don't want spend to many resources.

Comment: Did you find an effective way of managing notifications with Realm?

Comment: I had to stop the project, and the other one where i work uses firebase who has a good notification logic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by using **react-native-push-notification** npm to schedule local notifications.

Example code:

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
  date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)), // in 60 secs
  actions: ["ReplyInput"],
  reply_placeholder_text: "Write your response...", // (required)
  reply_button_text: "Reply" // (required)
});
```

Check out the **official docs** for more understanding

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification